# What did Yuji do to his sister Kazuki?

Tags: grisaia

In *Grisaia no Rakuen (Paradise)*, after saving Yuji and retrieving the real body of Thanatos (Kazuki actually), there was a scene (aboard the ship Mihama Academy) when Yuji got pissed or irritated due to Kazuki's "bossy" attitude. Yuji yelled "Kazuki!" and then he dragged her to some place on the deck. Afterwards, when they were "finished" Kazuki said: "Dont ever do that to other girls anymore..."

My question is: What did Yuuji do to Kazuki? Is there a manga that explains this?

Comment: The show was based on an eroge, so it would be very obvious what he did to Kazuki. Plus, she said "You must not do 'those thing' to any girls other than your sister.", emphasis on the word OTHER. So, you should have been able to infer that they had sex.

Comment: @MikeAgustin not all that strange. public sex can be a turn on for people

Comment: @Memor-X im just kinda puzzled, why didnt they show the clip? they are other anime that shows intimate scenes like "futari ecchi"..

Comment: @MikeAgustin to my understanding it's a choice on who the targeted demographic is and what the studio wants to be the classification rating. showing sex scenes will get the series restricted to certain timeslots on TV (such as being late late night) and ratings for home release like with Speed Grapher which in Australia is MA 15+ which is the level bellow from R18+ Restricted (which i think is the level bellow X). i'm not sure about Japanese classifications or what it was for Grisaia no Rakuen but i assume not showing it at all allowed them to air the show at their targetted audiance

Comment: @Memor-X I kind'a rewatched the anime, and there I remembered there was a scene about yuuji doing Julia's "first time". I wonder why they didn't show deck scene.

Comment: @MikeAgustin i dare say the incest would play a factor in that. i havn't seen the series or played the game so i've no idea

Comment: @ Mike Agustin That scene with JB was also not directly shown, similar to how it is here, just implied by showing them lying on the bed together, thereby making it more obvious than this scene with Kazuki here. Plus, there was also Yuji's scenes with Asako, which were also not shown but directly said in JB's conversation with Asako.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really got not much reference [here](http://tarowy.blomaga.jp/articles/65014.html) but there are two versions to this story in the game, the safe mode where it was Yuji giving Kazuki a shoulder massage and the 18+ mode where they had sex, not sure which side the anime adapted but I think it is the 18+ side with that ambiguous scene but it is totally up to the watcher's imagination here. In that link, the commenters mentioned what they thought of the episode compared to the game so just go ahead and read those, if that is insufficient as evidence then I will leave the proper answering to someone else. But yes, they totally did say that they had sex in the game.

[image]

Comment: Generally the trend i find is that if there is an all ages version of a 18+ Visual Novel and the anime isn't hentai it'll will adapt the all ages version, example are Fate/Stay Night (where Realta Nua was used) and Tears to Tiara (where the PS3 Remake was used) and i would suspect Utawarerumono as well (where the PS2 version was used). though thinking of a sister saying that her brother can't do massages for other girls is kinda strange but i've neither played the visual novel or seen the anime so i don't know if the scene is from an incest route

Comment: Yes, it is most likely they adapted the safe version since the sex scenes were missing from both the Kajitsu and Eden animes and the commenters said how that scene was missing from here as well, and it is just what she said here that makes me think it is from the 18+ side. So, yes, I cannot prove whether it is the 18+ storyline or just a shoulder massage.

Answer (score 1):

They totally have sex. In the Labyrinth episode, where Yuuji was young, Kazuki takes him in the bath and explains what incest is. When they get in the bath and it fades out, Yuuji says that he, "learned a lot from his sister." The fact that Asako thought she took his first time was a misunderstanding from Yuuji's lack of communication. He'd obviously been molested while under the "care" of Heath Oslo, so even though Asako sad she took his first time, she was... well.. a little further down the line. Even if this hadn't been based on an eroge, which I didn't realize it was, that scene when the siblings were young, mixed with the fact she said he mustn't do that with any other girl than her, they had sex. And that Kazuki isn't as knowledgeable as she thinks.

Also, as a side note, I think the fact that Yuuji then thought to himself, "What does she mean by 'those things'," means that he obviously doesn't see what's wrong with it, which makes sense, since he's been having a lot of sex, willing or not, since he was young. Kazuki playing the pronoun game probably just confused him.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure he had sex with her now that I've think about it. This is by no means canon but from what I can tell, is that he has been raised having sex almost constantly with Asako. So it would not be a stretch to say he took having sex as a way to express his love. He did specifically say Asako is the most important woman to him.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the eroge it's based on, it is very *likely* that they had sex. Considering the complete and total loss of his family before either him or Kazuki were at an age where someone had explained the nuances of sex, it is entirely likely neither of them realize that them having intercourse is actually wrong. They have both been detatched from mainstream society for some time with the exception of Kazuki who lived on the internet, and if you can find a place where someone can justify incest and almost make it sound legit, it's definitely the internet.

Regardless, I choose to pretend that he just gave her a shoulder rub for obvious reasons. "You mustn't do those things with girls other than your sister" obviously does not make ANY sense at all in a sexual context, I mean really.